# Firefox crash when called by Selenium Remote Driver on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, perl, firefox, selenium

I have just installed the [Selenium Remote Driver](https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver) on my Mac OS X 10.8.5 machine, and using Firefox 43.0.4 (the latest stable to date) when running this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Firefox;

my $firefox = Selenium::Firefox->new;
$firefox->get('http://www.google.com');
```

causes the browser to open, and then crash, outputting the following error to console:

```
kernel[0]: firefox-bin (map: ...) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: ..., region ...->.... While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
```

Any clue as to what might be causing this?
Is it a programming error on my part?
Should I be using some specific flag to prevent this?
Or is this something I should report as a bug?
Any help is much appreciated. You will have noticed this is my first post to the site. I hope it is not out of order in any way, please excuse me if it is.
Thank you in advance.
Best regards,

Mark.

Comment: try with down grading the firefox.. FF39 working very well for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to an issue with Selenium and FX 43 64bit. As of now there is no fix, only workarounds. These include:

- Updating to newest Selenium version which makes FX not check addon signatures.
- Using 32 bit version of Firefox
- Using an older version of Firefox, e.g. 42

See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1431 for more details.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info... didn't think about the architecture issue. Will try other methods maybe, and if I have no choice will downgrade as suggested.
Thanks Hubert Grzeskowiak and murali seleniumtrainer